# How do I animate changing of div height from the bottom up using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Is there anyway i can animate the changing of a div box height from bottom to top, instead of top to bottom?

This div box is absolute positioned and acts kind of like a curtain to the contents underneath it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WHY NOT TO USE `slideUp()` / `slideDown()` :

'cause it's prone to bugs if multiple / fast mouse actions are registered.

Try in the demo, even using `.stop()` method you cannot achieve the result like  below:

---

Here is a slight modification using `.animate()` and height toggling:
(just need: `position:absolute; bottom:0px; display:none;`)

### *[demo 1 (a nice way to do it)](http://jsbin.com/udiriv/52/edit)*

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.curtain').stop().animate({height: 'toggle'});
});
```

---

### *[demo 2](http://jsbin.com/udiriv/edit#javascript,html,live)*

Another way is:

```
var boxHeight = $('.box').innerHeight();  // get element height

$('.curtain').css({top:boxHeight}); // push 'curtain' down

$('.box').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.curtain').stop().animate({top: 0});  // animate to desired top distance
},function(){
  $(this).find('.curtain').stop().animate({top: boxHeight}); // and on mouseout - back down
});
```

Comment: cheers dude. I like Demo 2 better as i need to control the height.

Comment: @MakkyNZ cheers to you too! Thought about that so i gave an example! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').slideUp();
```

This uses [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) to animate the div to `0px` height from bottom to top

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect by animating the top and height simultaneously. You will simply need to determine the final height.

For example, assuming that you have:

```
#mydiv{
    top: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
};
```

and you want to end up with the div animated to:

```
#mydiv{
    top: 0px; /* new top */
    height: 500px; /* new height */
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
};
```

jquery code, when you click the div:

```
$("#mydiv").on("click", function(){
   $('#mydiv').animate( {"top": "0px", "height": "500px" } );
});
```